# Create index on column in one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, orm

I have a one-to-many relationship between two classes like this:

```
class Parent {
    List<Child> children;
}

class Child {
    String name;
}
```

I'm using an `.hbm.xml` file to define my mapping from Java classes to tables. Something like this:

```
<class name="Parent" table="parent">
    <list name="children">
        <key column="parent_id" />
        <list-index column="idx" />
        <one-to-many class="Child" />
    </list>
</class>

<class name="Child" table="child">
    <property name="name" type="string" />
</class>
```

That works fine.

Now I want to create a column index (not a list index) on the `Child.parent_id` column. It seems that the `<one-to-many>` tag doesn't allow any nested `<column>` tags, so I tried adding a bidirectional association to the `Child` mapping like this:

```
<many-to-one name="parent" insert="false" update="false">
    <column name="parent_id" index="true">
</many-to-one>
```

But I get an exception:

```
 org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for parent in class Child
```

So, how can I create an index on the `Child.parent_id` column without adding a `parent` field to the `Child` class? I'm using Hibernate 3.5.6 and PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: How you imagine to have index on column that doesn't exist?
You need to have parent_id in child class if you want to have bidirectional association or index.

Comment: There is a `parent_id` column. It seems to be created by the `<one-to-many>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I didn't get it what you are looking for, but I think I figure it out.

You defined the `list-index` which is used to save the index of the java.util.List and not the parent_id of the Child. So you are looking how to create real database index. That can be easy done by annotation like this;

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
@Index(name = "idx_parent_id", columnNames = "parent_id")
private List<Child> images = new ArrayList<Child>();
```

And in xml configuration would look like,

```
  <list name="children">
   <key>
    <column index="parent_id_idx" name="parent_id"/>
   </key>
   <list-index column="idx"/>
   <one-to-many class="hr.winkme.server.model.entities.Child"/>
  </list>
```

Hope it helps.